# How to build dynamic-library in qt static build

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator, dynamic-library

I try to build my dynamic library project in linux. I build my qt library in static. But  if i use it to build my proj, qt creator builds only libname.a file. However if i use original qt library qt creator builds libname.so file. Wats is the problem?
Pro file.

```
`#------------------------------------------------- # # 
Project created by QtCreator 2020-10-22T07:46:59 
# #------------------------------------------------- 
QT -= gui TARGET = up_api_send 
TEMPLATE = lib 
DEFINES += UP_API_SEND_LIBRARY 
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += up_api_send.cpp 
HEADERS += up_api_send.h\ 
           up_api_send_global.h 
unix { target.path = /usr/lib INSTALLS += target } 
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libplot/ -lplot2 
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/headerplot 
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/headerplot`
```

Build log.
Original library.

```
16:04:07: Start build project up_api_send...
16:04:07: Starts: «/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake» /root/QT/QT_SO/up_api_send/up_api_send.pro -spec linux-g++
Info: creating stash file /root/QT/QT_SO/build-up_api_send-Desktop_Qt_5_7_1_GCC_64bit-Release/.qmake.stash
16:04:07: Процесс «/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake» success.
16:04:07: Starts: «/usr/bin/make» qmake_all
make: Target `qmake_all' action is not required.
16:04:07: Process «/usr/bin/make» success.
16:04:07: Starts: «/usr/bin/make» 
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DUP_API_SEND_LIBRARY -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../up_api_send -I. -I../up_api_send/headerplot -I/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o up_api_send.o ../up_api_send/up_api_send.cpp
../up_api_send/up_api_send.cpp: In member function ‘bool DgateTrans::PLOT_sendMsg(const char*, const char*, int)’:
../up_api_send/up_api_send.cpp:143:19: warning: unused variable ‘tid’ [-Wunused-variable]
/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/bin/moc -DUP_API_SEND_LIBRARY -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/root/QT/QT_SO/up_api_send -I/root/QT/QT_SO/up_api_send/headerplot -I/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/include/c++/4.7 -I/usr/include/c++/4.7/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/c++/4.7/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include ../up_api_send/up_api_send.h -o moc_up_api_send.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DUP_API_SEND_LIBRARY -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../up_api_send -I. -I../up_api_send/headerplot -I/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_up_api_send.o moc_up_api_send.cpp
rm -f libup_api_send.so.1.0.0 libup_api_send.so libup_api_send.so.1 libup_api_send.so.1.0
g++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib -shared -Wl,-soname,libup_api_send.so.1 -o libup_api_send.so.1.0.0 up_api_send.o moc_up_api_send.o  -L/root/QT/QT_SO/up_api_send/libplot/ -lplot2 -L/opt/Qt5.7.1/5.7/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Core -lpthread  
ln -s libup_api_send.so.1.0.0 libup_api_send.so
ln -s libup_api_send.so.1.0.0 libup_api_send.so.1
ln -s libup_api_send.so.1.0.0 libup_api_send.so.1.0
16:04:09: Process «/usr/bin/make» success.
16:04:09: Time passed: 00:02.
```

Build log. Static library.

```
 16:05:00: Start build project up_api_send...
16:05:00: Settings not changed, stage qmake is skipped.
16:05:00: Starts: «/usr/bin/make» 
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DUP_API_SEND_LIBRARY -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../up_api_send -I. -I../up_api_send/headerplot -I/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/include -I/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o up_api_send.o ../up_api_send/up_api_send.cpp
../up_api_send/up_api_send.cpp: In member function ‘bool DgateTrans::PLOT_sendMsg(const char*, const char*, int)’:
../up_api_send/up_api_send.cpp:143:19: warning: unused variable ‘tid’ [-Wunused-variable]
/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/bin/moc -DUP_API_SEND_LIBRARY -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I/root/QT/QT_SO/up_api_send -I/root/QT/QT_SO/up_api_send/headerplot -I/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/include -I/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/include/c++/4.7 -I/usr/include/c++/4.7/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include/c++/4.7/backward -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include-fixed -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -I/usr/include ../up_api_send/up_api_send.h -o moc_up_api_send.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DUP_API_SEND_LIBRARY -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../up_api_send -I. -I../up_api_send/headerplot -I/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/include -I/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/include/QtCore -I. -I/usr/local/Qt-5.7.1/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o moc_up_api_send.o moc_up_api_send.cpp
rm -f libup_api_send.a
ar cqs libup_api_send.a up_api_send.o moc_up_api_send.o
16:05:02: Process «/usr/bin/make» success.
16:05:02: Time passed: 00:02.
```

Maybe i wrote wrong parameters when build qt library?

```
./configure -platform linux-g++ 
-release  
-static  
-fontconfig  
-opensource  
-confirm-license 
-gtkstyle 
-no-webkit
-nomake demos
-nomake examples
```

Comment: Can you post your .pro file?

Comment: Do you have an English version?

Comment: @JLev i translated logs.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe having Qt configured with `-static` will add `CONFIG+=static` by default in qmake, so it might be worth trying to add `CONFIG-=static`. However, it is weird to link a static Qt build into a shared library. If the program, or any of th other libraries also use Qt, you will end up with multiple definitions of Qt symbols.

Comment: @BenjaminT I want to remove dependencies from library. Wats why i build qt library in static.

Comment: @BenjaminT config -= static did not help(((